# angularjs ui-grid showing total in footer

Tags: angularjs, footer

I am trying to implement ui-grid and want to show total for few columns in the footer as explained here:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/105_footer

Here I noticed that initially when the page is loaded, you can no total or average or any value is displayed in the footer but as soon as you click somewhere on grid or scroll inside the grid the footer values get displayed.

This is something a strange behavior.

I am facing the same issue like this, initially when my page gets load the total is not displayed but if I click somewhere on grid or do some similar activity the total gets displayed.

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

CODE: (app.js)

```
{ field: 'age', aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.avg, aggregationHideLabel: true, width: '13%' },
```

//
Just set aggregationHideLabel to false and you will be able to see a total.

```
aggregationHideLabel: false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be doing some DOM manipulation which may stop binding and you might wants to trigger a digest cycle like this

```
if (!scope.$$phase)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Oops sorry, I am not able to get this, it would be nice if you can explain in some detail and also can you tell me how can monitor whether some operation is stopping my binding.

Comment: try putting above two lines after all scope related assignment is done. There isn't any specific way to monitor the stop binding, but usually it happens when  we do some DOM manipulation using jQuery!

Comment: Hmm, I will try that but if you have noticed in their demo (the link I have provided) same behavior is happening.